# Django1.2/google-appengine debug "KeyError: 'REQUEST_METHOD" Error

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I have a Python 2.7 project that uses both Django 1.2 and `google-appengine`.  To run the file I type `python main.py`.  In doing so, I get the following error.  I am not familiar with either `google-appengine` or Django to know why I am getting this error.  Also the project has a folder called `lib` which has a folder in it called `appengine`. I tried to set a path to this folder but it seems to do nothing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vicktree/.local/share/virtualenvs/noahs-app-M81YxnJh/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/vicktree/.local/share/virtualenvs/noahs-app-M81YxnJh/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webapp2.py", line 1595, in handle_exception
    return handler(request, response, e)
  File "/home/vicktree/Desktop/noah/web/noahs-app/handlers/hoptoad_handler.py", line 82, in handle_500_error
    notify_hoptoad(exception, request, False, False)
  File "/home/vicktree/Desktop/noah/web/noahs-app/handlers/hoptoad_handler.py", line 76, in notify_hoptoad
    send_to_hoptoad(generate_xml(exn, request, debug_mode), use_ssl)
  File "/home/vicktree/Desktop/noah/web/noahs-app/handlers/hoptoad_handler.py", line 34, in generate_xml
    xml << ('url', request.url)
  File "/home/vicktree/.local/share/virtualenvs/noahs-app-M81YxnJh/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 495, in url
    url = self.path_url
  File "/home/vicktree/.local/share/virtualenvs/noahs-app-M81YxnJh/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 467, in path_url
    bpath_info = bytes_(self.path_info, self.url_encoding)
  File "/home/vicktree/.local/share/virtualenvs/noahs-app-M81YxnJh/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/descriptors.py", line 70, in fget
    return req.encget(key, encattr=encattr)
  File "/home/vicktree/.local/share/virtualenvs/noahs-app-M81YxnJh/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 153, in encget
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PATH_INFO'
ERROR:root:'REQUEST_METHOD'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vicktree/.local/share/virtualenvs/noahs-app-M81YxnJh/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webapp2.py", line 1546, in __call__
    return response(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/vicktree/.local/share/virtualenvs/noahs-app-M81YxnJh/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/exc.py", line 358, in __call__
    is_head = environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'HEAD'
KeyError: 'REQUEST_METHOD'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1426, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 1423, in main
    run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 101, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 119, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    result = application(env, _start_response)
  File "/home/vicktree/.local/share/virtualenvs/noahs-app-M81YxnJh/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webapp2.py", line 1548, in __call__
    return self._internal_error(e)(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/vicktree/.local/share/virtualenvs/noahs-app-M81YxnJh/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/exc.py", line 358, in __call__
    is_head = environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'HEAD'
KeyError: 'REQUEST_METHOD'
```

My Questions:

1. Am I using the incorrect version of `google-appengine` (version=272.0.0)?
2. What is the particular thing causing the error. I do not understand what `REQUEST_METHOD` means

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running your Google App Engine Standard (First Generation) app locally, you should use the `dev_appserver.py` local development server instead.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server for more details.